# Error Trapping for dialog box reply

Tags: vba, excel

How can I improve upon this code to apply logic based on the user's response to a SaveAs Dialog Box 'do you want to overwrite existing file' question:

```
Sub SaveFile(fName As String)

cancelSave = False
Retry:
saveAsFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=fName, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
If saveAsFileName <> False Then
    If Not Dir(saveAsFileName) <> vbNullString Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=saveAsFileName
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=saveAsFileName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbook, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            GoTo Retry
        Else
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
Else
    cancelSave = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where are `cancelSave` and `saveAsFileName` declared (are they declared)? Is `cancelSave` used anywhere? This would make a better question with additional context code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Both variables are publicly declared in the declaration section in the main module. If `cancelSave = True` then it exits the main module's subroutine.

Comment: Hmm now you're making me want to review much more than just this procedure! Could you [edit] and include the code that uses `cancelSave` and `saveAsFileName`?

Answer (score 4):

It might be a personal preference, but I find indenting the entire procedure body massively helps making a module easier to read - the only thing that's left in column 1 is module-level declarations, procedure signatures, and line labels. Conversely, *not* indenting the entire procedure body makes it harder to tell which procedure starts/ends where in a module.

> ```
> Sub SaveFile(fName As String)
> ```

The procedure is *implicitly* `Public`, which makes it hard to tell whether it's meant to be used in the same module, or if it's meant to be called by code outside the module. If it's meant to be used in the same module, make it `Private`. If not, make it *explicitly* `Public`.

The `fName` parameter is *implicitly* passed `ByRef`, which means if `SaveFile` reassigns the parameter, the new value will be visible at the call site. If that's intentional, an *explicit* `ByRef` modifier should be there. Given the parameter isn't reassigned in the body of the procedure, it should be passed `ByVal`.

It's not clear *how* the procedure is used, but it seems `cancelSave` is declared outside the procedure. If it's in the same module, it should be `Private`. If it's in another module, then it's `Public` and you have a global variable... and in all likelihood (assuming `SaveFile` is called from some `BeforeSave` event handler) it could be avoided by making the procedure a `Function` that returns a `Boolean`:

```
Public Function SaveFile(ByVal fName As String) As Boolean
```

I **strongly** doubt you *actually* need a global variable for this.

---

The procedure feels wrong, because error-handling logic is intertwined with the actual procedure logic; these `On Error` and `GoTo` statements obscure the intent of the code.

Typically, error-handling is done in a dedicated *subroutine*, and no `GoTo` statement is needed - you want to run some logic in a **loop** *until* the user cancels out; it's much clearer if you use one of VBA's many loop structures instead of implementing that `GoTo`-loop.

Let's take a moment to consider this alternative implementation:

```
Public Function SaveFile(Optional ByVal initialPath As String = vbNullString) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Dim cancelSaveHandler As Boolean

    Dim completed As Boolean
    While Not completed

        Dim result As Variant
        result = Application.GetSaveAsFileName(InitialFileName:=initialPath, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

        If VarType(result) = vbBoolean Then
            'cancelling GetSaveAsFileName dialog returns False:
            cancelSaveHandler = True
            completed = Not result
        'ElseIf Dir(result) = vbNullString Then
        '    'selected file doesn't exist, try saving:
        '    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=result, FileFormat:=xlWorkbook, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
        Else
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs result
        End If

    Wend

    SaveFile = cancelSaveHandler
    Exit Function

CleanFail:
    completed = (MsgBox("An unexpected error has occurred while saving. Try again?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation) = vbNo)
    Resume Next
End Function
```

Notice:

- The parameter is `Optional`, because it's not *really* required; it's also named in a way that doesn't suggest that *that's* the name we're saving the file with.
- The loop is explicit; there's no `GoTo` jump.
- The error-handling logic is completely separated from the procedure's actual logic.
- Error handling doesn't leave unexpected errors dangling unhandled, and only ever runs when a runtime error happens.
- No implicit conversion from `Variant/String` or `Variant/Boolean` when evaluating whether the `GetSaveAsFileName` dialog was cancelled.
- No more double-negative when checking if the file exists.
- Checking if the file exists is redundant if we're going to save either way; `xlWorkbook` is the default format anyway, and what's wrong with prompting for conflict resultion (the default behavior) if/when applicable?
- User knows what's happening and why, at all times.
- We're returning a value to the caller instead of assigning a global variable: *there are no side-effects to global state*.

In an ideal world, there would also be a `VB_Description` attribute, to describe what the function does:

```
Attribute SaveFile.VB_Description = "Prompts user for a non-existing file name and saves the active workbook. Returns True if 'BeforeSave' handler should be cancelled."
```

You can set this procedure attribute via the *Object Browser*, by browsing to the function, right-clicking, selecting "Properties" in the context menu, and entering a value in the "Description" box. That description will then be visible in the *Object Browser*:

[image: VB_Description attribute in the Object Browser]

Ideally all public members should have a description.

Comment: Very insightful! I'll have to study it a bit but I appreciate that thoughtful explanation.

Answer (score 3):

### Your logic is horribly unintuitive

The human brain is not good at basic logic. It is absolutely terrible at complex logic. Whenever you have a `[condition]` statement, you should make it as easy to understand as possible. This means using as few logical operators as possible. Do everything in small steps. Give names to logical outputs like `thingExists` or `isValid`.

---

You have 5 seconds to explain what the following conditions are checking for.
**GO:**

```
If Not Dir(saveAsFileName) <> vbNullString Then
```

Versus

```
Dim fileDoesNotExist as Boolean
fileDoesNotExist = (Dir(saveAsFileName) = vbNullString)

If fileDoesNotExist Then
```

Notice how you don't have to even explain the second one because it already explains itself.

---

This leads us to the golden rule: **Don't make me think**. The harder I have to think to deconstruct your logic, the more likely it is that I'll misunderstand it, and if I misunderstand what's going on then I'm going to introduce bugs when I try to do anything with it.

Name things. Make things sound like what they are. Be verbose if it makes the sequence of operations easier to follow.

Also, this:

```
If saveAsFileName <> False Then
```

Is confusing, because it is **literally** the same as writing:

```
If saveAsFileName = True Then
```

Which is the same as:

```
If saveAsFileName Then
```

---

### Tell your user what's going on

```
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=saveAsFileName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbook, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        GoTo Retry
```

This is going to cause all sorts of confusion.

I'm a user. I put in a filename and click <kbd>Save As</kbd>

What I don't know is that the filename is going to cause a 1004 Error. What do I see?

**Nothing**.

Let's follow the execution for a second.

1) I click <kbd>Save As</kbd>

2) The code passes the `If` checks.

3) We get to `On Error Resume Next`

4) The code tries to save the workbook and fails

5) `Goto Retry`

6) The code re-opens the `GetSaveAsFilename` dialog box.

As a user, all I see is the result of step 6. I clicked <kbd>Save As</kbd> and all that happened was that the box where I put my filename is now blank. WTF? I do the natural thing and try again. I type in my filename, click <kbd>Save As</kbd> and ... **W.T.F.** same thing again. "This useless thing is broken" I think to myself, and now I'm annoyed because I'm on try number 3 and the program isn't responding to me.

Imagine the difference if we just added a little explanation:

```
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "That filename caused an error. Please try again or choose a different filename"
        Goto Retry
    End If
```

And now the user understands what's happening and knows what they have to do to fix it.

As before, **don't make me think**. Tell me what I need to know, as cleanly and simply as possible.

Comment: IMO `If saveAsFileName Then` is horrible, because the `GetSaveAsFileName` returns a `Variant` that will be a `Boolean` when the dialog is cancelled, or a `String` when a filename is provided. Implicitly converting the `String` to a `Boolean` for that condition just doesn't look right.

Comment: @Mat'sMug True. Probably a good idea to give that a named condition as well.

Comment: @Zak `If saveAsFileName = True Then` will not work according to Mat's Mug's comment. It must be `If saveAsFileName <> False` to work properly. Furthermore, the 'do you want to overwrite this file' dialog box appears after the `.SaveAs` method is run. The `Err.Number = 1004` only returns True if 'No' or 'Cancel' is clicked, taking you back to the Save As dialog box to either change the name or cancel. If 'Yes' is clicked then it overwrites the file.

Comment: @Brian race-conditions aside (e.g. another user on the network created that exact same file just a split-millisecond after you checked if it already exists), how is that prompt even possible, given you're checking if the file already exists and only attempt to save when it doesn't?

Comment: @Mat'sMug My code does not only attempt to save if the file doesn't exist. It saves if it doesn't and gives the user the choice to overwrite it or save it as a new one if it does. Reports are sometimes run several times a day and it generates the same file name with today's date.